# How to make a hand armature hold an object, but with collision on the object; so the hand doesn’t go through the object?

Tags: collision

Say I wanted my hand armature to hold a book, and I wanted to animate different poses of holding the book, but not have to worry about the fingers passing through the book; as though the book itself has a boundary. Therefore, the fingers would always be on the book… No matter how I pose the hand.

I’d like to be able to do that, and somehow control its release from the book as well, so I may have the other hand do the same.

Is what I am attempting a possibility? I’m curious; as to how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, but if you give a *Child Of* constraint to your hand controlling bone, with the book as target, it will probably make things easier, as you'll control the hand with the book:

[image]

[image]